# How to concatenate two values supplied with two keys in different HashTables?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to concatenate two values provided with two keys in distinct HashTables.

## Code

```
$caminho = @{
    Aplicacao = "C:\Users\marconi.barroso\Desktop\APP";
    jdk = "C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin"
}

$arquivo = @{
    log = "log.txt";
    apk = "lojasrede.apk"
}


if(Test-Path $caminho.Aplicacao\$arquivo.log) {
    Remove-Item $caminho.Aplicacao\$arquivo.log
}
```

## Error:

> Test-Path: Can not associate argument with parameter 'Path' because it
>   is null. In the line: 1 character: 11

Comment: This is a PowerShell question about concatenating variables. Should be on-topic for SU I would think—it's not a complex question—glad SU can help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `+ "\" +` between the two array variables and enclose that within parenthesis e.g. `($caminho.Aplicacao + "\" + $arquivo.log)`. The `+` [plus sign] will concatenate the `\` [backslash] string that's enclosed with `""` [double quotes]. So just place that (`+ "\" +`) right between the two variables and your logic stays nearly the same and works as expected.

---

**PowerShell**

```
$caminho = @{
    Aplicacao = "C:\Users\marconi.barroso\Desktop\APP";
    jdk = "C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin"
}

$arquivo = @{
    log = "log.txt";
    apk = "lojasrede.apk"
}


if(Test-Path ($caminho.Aplicacao + "\" + $arquivo.log)) {
    Remove-Item ($caminho.Aplicacao + "\" + $arquivo.log)
}
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Concatenating in PowerShell](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-concat.html)

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to concatenate two values provided with two keys in distinct HashTables.

You are missing the required **-Path** parameter.  You were also not concatenating the two paths, which can be done with **Join-Path**, resulting in what you were trying to do.  The missing **-Path** parameter in **Test-Path** was only half the problem.

```
Test-Path (Join-Path -Path $caminho.jdk -ChildPath $arquivo.log)
```

The above command correctly returned **True** for me.

[Test-Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-6)

[Join-Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways,

```
if(Test-Path (Join-Path $caminho.Aplicacao $arquivo.log)) {
    Remove-Item (Join-Path $caminho.Aplicacao $arquivo.log)}
}
```

I'd use Join-Path first and store the path in a variable as it is to be used at leeast twice.